# Packaging a JavaFX App for MacOS X using NetBeans on a Windows system

Tags: xml, netbeans, ant, javafx-2, packaging

I'm developing a JavaFX Desktop application using NetBeans 8 on Windows, but I'm not able to create deployment packaging which is able to run on MacOS. I have shared `build.xml`. I'm able to generate the `Demo.app` file but whenever I try to run it on Mac, it shows an error like "*unable to load java runtime environment*".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Demo" default="default" basedir="."xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
<description>Builds, tests, and runs the project </description>
<import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
 <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
     uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
     classpath=".:path/to/sdk/lib/ant-javafx.jar"/>

    <target name="-post-jfx-deploy" >
   <fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}" 
              nativeBundles="all" verbose="true"
              outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}"  outfile="${application.title}">
      <fx:application name="${application.title}" 
                      mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
      <fx:resources>
          <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}"
                      includes="Demo.jar"/>
      </fx:resources>
      <fx:info title="${application.title}" 
               vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
    </fx:deploy>          
 </target>

<taskdef name="bundleapp"
     classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"
     classpath="lib/appbundler-1.0.jar" />

<target name="bundle-demo">
<bundleapp outputdirectory="dist"
    name="Demo"
    displayname="DemoSyncApp"
    identifier="com.demo.DemoApp"
    mainclassname="com.demo.DemoApp">
    <classpath file="dist/Demo.jar" />
     
 </bundleapp>
 </target> 



 </project>
```

Comment: NetBeans has a [wizard for creating native packaged apps](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html).  It's probably easier for you to use that than debug a custom build.xml.

Comment: Actually, I also don't think packaging a JavaFX application for an OS other than the OS you are building on is a supported feature of the JavaFX 8 packager, so I don't think you will be able to do what you are attempting to do (package an OS X application on a Windows machine).  I think you would need to create the package on an OS X machine for it to work.

Comment: i tried to generate package using appbundler jar. Demo.app package is created .also its contains proper structure ,but it doesn't contain required file. I will try to create package by the way solution you suggested.  Thanx!

Comment: package created on mac machine by  using eclipse.

Comment: Hi DannyGolhar, how did you create a package for Mac OS in eclipse? What steps did you use? I need to package my application which is on Netbeans IDE on a Windows Computer. Kindly advise.

Comment: @JosephMwema You need to run your eclipes project on mac machine to create package for Mac.                         http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part7 Please follow this tutorial link. hope it helps